# Why the following code shows an error?

Tags: perl, perl-module, getopt, getopt-long

I want to pass arguments from the command line so i had tried the following code but it throws an error?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use Getopt::Std;
print "raw data:@ARGV\n";
my $site=getopts('bangalore','norwood','limerick');
if($site)
{
print "success";
}
else
{
die "error";
}
print "final data:@ARGV \n";
```

Comment: getopt, getopts - Process single-character switches with switch clustering.

Comment: [Refer](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html)

Comment: Why are you loading Getopt::Long and then ignoring it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not correct. Please go through the documentation first: http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html

Below is an attempt to guess what you were trying to achieve.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
my $city;
print "raw data:@ARGV\n";
GetOptions ("city=s" => \$city) or die("Error in command line arguments\n");
my $site = $city;
if($site){
    print "success: City is $city\n";
}
print "Final data:@ARGV \n";
```

Output:

```
chankeypathak@stackoverflow:~/Desktop$ perl test.pl -city=bangalore
raw data:-city=bangalore
success: City is bangalore
Final data:
```

Output when passed incorrect param:

```
chankeypathak@stackoverflow:~/Desktop$ perl test.pl -blah=blah
raw data:-blah=blah
Unknown option: blah
Error in command line arguments
```

Comment: if i want to pass only the four city like(a,b,c,d).How i can pass it in array.if the city name is r it should print unsuccess.

Comment: Please go through the link, first understand how to accept the parameters. After that you just have to add conditionals based on your need.

Comment: @test data, `--city a,b,c,d` is still only one parameter. You are actually asking how to split a value. You can use: `my @cities = $city ? split(/,/, $city) : ();`

Answer (score 0):

[Thanks to: alvinalexander](http://alvinalexander.com/perl/perl-getopts-command-line-options-flags-in-perl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# a perl getopts example
# alvin alexander, http://www.devdaily.com

use strict;
use Getopt::Std;

# declare the perl command line flags/options we want to allow
my %options=();
getopts("hj:ln:s:", \%options);

# test for the existence of the options on the command line.
# in a normal program you'd do more than just print these.
print "-h $options{h}\n" if defined $options{h};
print "-j $options{j}\n" if defined $options{j};
print "-l $options{l}\n" if defined $options{l};
print "-n $options{n}\n" if defined $options{n};
print "-s $options{s}\n" if defined $options{s};

# other things found on the command line
print "Other things found on the command line:\n" if $ARGV[0];
foreach (@ARGV)
{
  print "$_\n";
}
```